# how to redirect to a page if PDO transaction fails?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I need to redirect to a separate page to show error. header("Location: errorpage.php?errorcode=11"); after does not seem to work.

```
<?php
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydbase;charset=utf8", "user", "password");
try {
$db->beginTransaction();

$db->exec("SOME QUERY");

$db->commit();
} 

catch(PDOException $ex) {
$db->rollBack();
//Something went wrong so I need to redirect
header("Location: errorpage.php?errorcode=11");
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't redirect, then you're probably outputting before header. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything, as well as a warning about headers already sent. That, and/or your query failed.

Comment: or add `ob_start();` at the top, right beneath `<?php`, this will make sure the script is finnished before any output is sent :)

Comment: `ob_start()` may work, but is at best a hack. Sorting out the logic to prevent output is very much preferred.

Comment: After header('Location: errorpage.php?errorcode=11'); add exit(); , but first put <?php tag error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PDO's error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) is a little unusual. It has modes for throwing real exceptions, issuing PHP warnings, or just being silent.

Silent is the default. What has happened here is that no exception is ever thrown because you did not configure PDO to throw one.  So **the `catch` block is never entered and `header()` is never called**. Setup your `$db` object to throw exceptions:

```
// Ensure PHP's native error handling is showing
// on screen (to catch problems with header() itself)
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// Always in development, disabled in production
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydbase;charset=utf8", "user", "password");

// Turn on exceptions for PDO so the try/catch is meaningful
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
  $db->beginTransaction();
  $db->exec("SOME QUERY");
  $db->commit();
} 

catch(PDOException $ex) {
  $db->rollBack();
  //Something went wrong so I need to redirect
  header("Location: errorpage.php?errorcode=11");
  // Always make an explicit call to exit() after a redirection header.
  exit();
}
```

About `PDO::exec()`:

I know this is example code, but `exec()` is not usually the right method to use. If you are doing DDL statements, the transaction won't work since MySQL doesn't support that, and if you are doing things like `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` with any user input, you should be doing [`prepare()/execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) to create an injection-safe prepared statement instead.

Comment: adding $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); worked. My code is exactly similar except i used $db->exec("LOCK TABLE `mydbase`"); so had to add exceptions after i lock my table.

Comment: @styxtrooper I'm glad it works for you. `exec()` is appropriate for a `LOCK TABLE` statement, but unless you have other `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` in there, the transaction won't be of much use. (I suspect you probably do, otherwise why would you lock it?)

Comment: I'm going to leave the part about exec() for future readers, though it is right for your LOCK TABLE command

Comment: much appreciated for your help. I do INSERT data, will consider prepare()/execute() for future projects. thank you.